# java method calling magic 8 ball

Tags: java

Here are the parameters:

Create a method called get8BallAnswers (2 point)
The method should have no parameters
The method will build the array of possible String answers (from BA5), and return the entire array

Overload the get8BallAnswers method (2 points) 
The method should have 1 integer parameter, where the user can pass a random number to it 
The method should return 1 possible String answer from the array. Hint: You can use the method you created in step 2 to retrieve the array of answers.

Create a method called magic8Ball that will basically run the whole program. (2 point)
It should ask the user to enter a question for the 8 Ball, generate a random number, and pass that to one of the methods above to get a response.
You will call this magic8Ball method in the main method.
The method should be called within the do-while loop, and repeat if the user wants to run the program again or not.

here's what I have:

```
package magic8; 
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class magic8Ball {

public static String[] get8BallAnswers() {
    String[] ball;
    return ball = new String[] {"Yes, of course!", "Without a doubt, yes.", 
"You can count on it.", "For sure!", "Ask me later.", "I'm not sure.", "I can't tell you right now", "I'll tell you after my nap.", "No way!", "I don't think so.", "Without a doubt, no.", "The answer is clearly No."};
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean run = true;{

    while (run) {
        magic8Ball();

        System.out.println("Do you want to try again, yes or no?");
        Scanner scnr = null;
        String go = scnr.nextLine();
        go = go.toLowerCase();

    if (go.equals("n")) {
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
        run = false;

    }

    if (go.equals("no")) {

        System.out.println("Goodbye");
        run = false;}
    }
}
}
public static void magic8Ball() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String response;
    System.out.println("Please ask me a question.");
    response = input.nextLine();


    Random gen = new Random();
    int pick = gen.nextInt(ball.length);
    System.out.println(ball[pick]);
    return;
}
}
```

I can't get the random number generator to pass a integer into the array ball to get a response.

Comment: "help?" isnt all that helpful as a question. What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: I can't get my random number generator to interact with my ball array

Comment: Set the `ball` array as a static variable.

Comment: @nickc this information should be part of your question. Please [edit] your question and explain where you need help.

Comment: @baudsp how do I do that?

Comment: I missed a part of the question. You'd have to create and initialize a `ball` variable in the method `magic8Ball`, like: `String[] ball = get8BallAnswers();`

Comment: @baudsp thanks so much!  last question:  it is saying there is an issue at line 21.  It'll run the program, but after asking "Do you want to try again" an error occurs.

Comment: I don't have the same version as you, so I don't know what's on line 21. But I'm guessing it's because you did not initialized the variable scanner.  It should be done this way: `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

private static String[] get8BallAnswers() {
    return new String[] {"Yes, of course!", "Without a doubt, yes.", "You can count on it.",
            "For sure!", "Ask me later.", "I'm not sure.", "I can't tell you right now",
            "I'll tell you after my nap.", "No way!", "I don't think so.",
            "Without a doubt, no.", "The answer is clearly No."};
}

private static String get8BallAnswers(int num) {
    return get8BallAnswers()[num];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        magic8Ball();

        System.out.println("Do you want to try again, yes or no?");

        if (scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase().contains("n")) {
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
            break;
        }
    }
}

private static void magic8Ball() {
    System.out.println("Please ask me a question.");
    scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println(get8BallAnswers(new Random().nextInt(get8BallAnswers().length)));
}
```